# What is the one-word English name for $\Omega$ in probability theory?

Tags: probability, notation, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I think we can call it a "sampling space" or "whole space". What are some shorter names for it? I've heard of the name "universe"; not sure if it is commonly accepted.

Comment: [Sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Wikipedia says "universal set". Is "universe" also a proper name?

Comment: Yes, you may use the term universe.  However, it tends to be used more frequently in set theory than probability, where the term sample space is more frequently used.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Make sense! many thanks!